# Calculate the sum of some inputs in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Part of my HTML code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: teamMembers -->
    <tr>
      <!-- ko foreach: days -->
      <td>
       <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
          <input  type="text" data-bind="value: number1">
          <input  type="text" data-bind="value: number2">
        <!-- /ko -->   
      </td>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <td>Total sum</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" data-bind='click: $root.addShift'>
          Add shift
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

The viewmodel code:

```
function TimeCardViewModel() {
    var self = this; 
    self.teamMembers=ko.observableArray();
    self.addShift = ko.pureComputed(function() { });               
}
$.ajax({
      type:"POST"  
      url: "/...json"
    }).then(function(data){   
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)  {
        timeCardViewModel.teamMembers.push({days:data[i]});   
      }   
    },
      function(){
        console.log('failure');
      }
   )
```

**days** is an `array of arrays`; each of the latter ones include one or more objects.Therefore, in the template, **$data** represents an array of objects which lie inside the **days** array! Each object has a **number1** property and a **number2** property.

I want to calculate the sum of the values of these two numbers for all the objects inside **days** which is an array of arrays and there are lots of them inside **teamMembers** which also is an array of arrays. So, I want this to be done for every element-array of **teamMembers**. How may I achieve that? I want **addShift** function to do that and get the sum inside `<td>Total sum</td>` which exists for every element of **teamMembers**.Sorry if not describing well the whole issue...

Comment: I see you're already using a `for` loop in some of your javascript?  Have you tried using one of those to add up your numbers?  Could you show some of the code you've already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working with these kinds of nested data, you might want to create viewmodels for each of your elements.

If I get your structure correctly there's:

1. A time card, which contains
2. Teammembers, which contain
3. Days, which contain
4. Shifts, which contain
5. Two numbers

If you define specific objects for each of these elements you get a good overview of the logic behind your computed values.

For example:

- the `totalHours` of a shift, is `number1 + number2`
- the `totalHours` of a day, is the `totalHours` of each shift summed
- etc.

Two things you'll benefit from using:

- [`ko.pureComputed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) to automatically recalculate total hours
- [`Array.prototype.reduce`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) to sum up all values in an array

I'd suggest taking a look at the example below to get a feel for how you could structure the elements that make up your `TimeCard`. You might not need this many class levels, but it makes it easier to follow.

Note that I didn't put in any code to convert your JSON data to new viewmodel instances. If you need help with that, let me know in the comments.

```js
function Shift(hoursA, hoursB) {
  var self = this;
  this.hoursA = ko.observable(hoursA);
  this.hoursB = ko.observable(hoursB);
  
  // Computed 1: Adds `number1` to `number2` when one of them
  //             changes
  this.totalHours = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.hoursA() + self.hoursB();
  });
};

function Day(initialShifts) {
  var self = this;
  this.shifts = ko.observableArray(initialShifts);

  // Computed 2: Adds the `totalHours` for each shift
  this.totalHours = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.shifts().reduce(function(result, shift) {
        return result + shift.totalHours();
    }, 0);
  });
};

function TeamMemberViewModel(initialDays) {
  var self = this;
  this.days = ko.observableArray(initialDays);  
  
  // Computed 3: Adds the `totalHours` for each day
  this.totalHours = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.days().reduce(function(result, day) {
        return result + day.totalHours();
    }, 0);
  });
};

function TimeCardViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.teamMembers = ko.observableArray();

  // Computed 4: Adds the `totalHours` for each member
  this.totalHours = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.teamMembers().reduce(function(result, member) {
        return result + member.totalHours();
    }, 0);
  });
};
```

Comment: Your answer is just fantastic. Please give me some time to peruse it since I am completely beginner to knockout. I might need you help again. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi again! If you are interested in winning 100 points (you deserve them) please have a look at my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001659/find-the-appropriate-dom-element. I will create a bounty on Sunday night